# Where should the other wire for this circuit connect?

Tags: repair

I want to repair this solar charging LED flashlight. When I took it apart I found that the black wire had broken off from the circuit and battery. I can see where it should connect to the battery, but I am not sure where it should connect to the circuit.

[image]

Comment: there is only one solder blob with some wire sticking out ... the device has some corrosion ... clean with isopropyl alcohol and a toothbrush

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added an arrow pointing at the pad.
This pad is connected to the negative side of the LEDs and also what looks like the negative side of the solar panel.

[image]

Comment: I forgot to say thank you! I found this in my drawer and was reminded to come back and thank you for your help.